# Using HttpClient and cookies to authenticate against OWIN

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I need to connect to a server we have here at the library so that I can use some internal API features.

This sever uses OWIN to authenticate, and I need to use cookies to help with the authentication. I've looked through a ton of examples on SO on how to use HttpClient with cookies, but I'm obviously still doing something wrong.

I set up this little test app, to try it, but I keep on getting an Interal Server Error:

> {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1,
>   Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{ 
>   Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'
>   cdnjs.cloudflare.com  X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?kjsdf83r3748ryefhkr4389r=?=  X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN  Date: Mon, 15 Aug 2016 14:37:28 GMT 
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0  Content-Length: 3312  Content-Type:
>   application/json; charset=utf-8}}

Here is my little test app:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Spock Library System...");
        GenerateBookLoan();
    }

    private static void GenerateBookLoan()
    {

        DateTime dueDate_Begin = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime dueDate_End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(13);

        var dueDate_Range = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"BeginDueDate", dueDate_Begin.ToString()},
                    {"EndDueDate", dueDate_End.ToString()}
                };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dueDate_Range);

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("library_API", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials, UseCookies = true };
        var cookies = new CookieContainer();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

        using (var http = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            try
            {
                http.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63432/");

                IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(http.BaseAddress).Cast<Cookie>();

                HttpResponseMessage response = http.PostAsync("api/books/loans/add", 
                    new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;


                Console.WriteLine(response);

        //do stuff//
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I need some advice on where to go next.  I've read through a ton of answers on here, but I can't seem to find one that fits my needs.

Thanks!

Comment: The error is on the server side, not client side...

Comment: status code suggests it is a server error